# How can I scale object to fit another object that shares the same shape but are diffrent size.

Tags: modeling

Please teach me how to scale precisely to fit another object.

I am trying to combine two objects that are made based on the same octagon.
I want to make these two object into one connected object. I am scaling looped edge, and am trying to fit that to the other object (see GIF attached). How can I scale it precisely to fit the other object?

If this process succeeds, I can use "remove double",and can combine these two objects.

- These are two objects I am trying to combine.
  [image]
- Process I am trying. But I cannot precisely scale to fit the other one.
  [image]

Comment: Delete the outer ring (the one selected on the gif), then select each remaining border and 'bridge edge loops'

Comment: Or enable **auto snap** (shift+ tab or use the magnet icon) and set it to edge. Note that by doing what you are asking to do you are going to end up with duplicated vertices/edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for you but, depending on the object type, it might take longer to complete as it's not automated.

You take one of the vertices on the outer ring (the inner ones that you want to match up). Then, you hold down the SHIFT key and select its corresponding vertex where you want it to be placed (on the inner ring). After that press Alt + M and choose "At Last" option. This way the vertex will be automatically placed at its desired position and the duplicate vertices will be removed, too. Now you can repeat the same process for the rest of the vertex pairs.

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Also, as cagotan mentioned in a comment, auto snap successfully allowed me to snap outer ring to inner ring. 
lemon's comment, "bridge edge loops" worked correctly in my case. 
Thank you, every one !!!